# Configuring third-party Helm charts from my application Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I can't seem to find any clear information on this anywhere, but is it possible in a Helm chart to require a third party, such as `stable/jenkins`, and specify configuration values?

All the examples I see are for running the `helm install` command directly but I would like to be able to configure it as part of my application.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In answer, @desaintmartin referred me to these documents in Slack:

- [Subcharts and Globals](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)
- [Requirements](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_best_practices/dependencies/)
- [Helm Dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/)

This led me to find the [specific part I was looking for](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart), where the parent chart can override sub-charts by specifying the chart name as a key in the parent `values.yaml`.

In the application chart's `requirements.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
- name: jenkins
  # Can be found with "helm search jenkins"
  version: '0.18.0'
  # This is the binaries repository, as documented in the GitHub repo
  repository: 'https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/'
```

Run:

```
helm dependency update
```

In the application chart's `values.yaml`:

```
# ...other normal config values

# Name matches the sub-chart
jenkins: 
  # This will be override "someJenkinsConfig" in the "jenkins" sub-chart
  someJenkinsConfig: value
```

Comment: For anyone trying to access the above links, please instead refer to the following:
[Subcharts and Globals](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/), [Requirements](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_best_practices/dependencies/), [Helm Dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/)

Comment: Thanks @BrianKo, I have updated the links